# Помогите! Ошибка CS1503 Аргумент 2: не удается преобразовать из "Discord.EmbedBuilder" в "Discord.Embed"

Tags: c#

```
Директивы если надо 
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Discord;
using Discord.Commands;
using Discord.WebSocket;
using Nezuko_Chan_Bot.Core.UserAccounts;
using NReco.ImageGenerator;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;


    [Command("person")]
           public async Task GetRandomPerson()
            {
                string json = "";
                using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                {
                    json = client.DownloadString("https://randomuser.me/api/?gender=female&nat=US");
                }

                var dataObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);

                string firstName = dataObject.results[0].name.first.ToString();
                string lastName = dataObject.results[0].name.last.ToString();
                string avatarURL = dataObject.results[0].picture.large.ToString();

                var embed = new EmbedBuilder();
                embed.WithThumbnailUrl(avatarURL);
                embed.WithTitle("Generated Person");
                embed.AddField("First Name", firstName);
                embed.AddField("Last Name", lastName);

                await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("", embed: embed);
            }
```

Comment: `embed.Build()`, не?

Comment: И как вы пробовали? Вот я прям четко [вижу](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44300770/discord-net-bot-embed-message), что у людей все прекрасно работает с `.Build()`

Comment: Серьезность Код Описание Проект Файл Строка Состояние подавления
Ошибка CS0246 Не удалось найти тип или имя пространства имен "embedBuilder" (возможно, отсутствует директива using или ссылка на сборку). крч та проблема с embed решилась теперь новая